# Is it possible to read a .tiff file from a remote service with dask?

Tags: image-processing, google-cloud-platform, dask, dask-distributed

I'm storing .tiff files on google cloud storage. I'd like to manipulate them using a distributed Dask cluster [installed with Helm on Kubernetes.](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/kubernetes-helm.html).

Based on the [dask-image repo](https://github.com/dask/dask-image/search?q=storage_options&unscoped_q=storage_options), the Dask documentation on [remote data services](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/remote-data-services.html), and the use of [storage_options](https://github.com/dask/dask/search?p=2&q=storage_options&unscoped_q=storage_options), right now it looks like remote reads from .zarr, .tdb, .orc, .txt, .parquet, and .csv formats are supported. Is that correct? If so, is there any recommended workaround for accessing remote .tiff files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off @MRocklin's answer, I found two ways to do it with `gcsfs`. One way with `imageio` for image parsing:

```
fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project="project_name")
img_bytes = fs.cat("bucket/blob_name.tif")
imageio.core.asarray(imageio.imread(img_bytes, "TIFF"))
```

And another with `opencv-python` for image parsing:

```
fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project="project_name")
fs.get("bucket/blob_name.tif", "local.tif")
img = np.asarray(cv2.imread("local.tif", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED))
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this.  I would probably use a library like `skimage.io.imread` along with `dask.delayed` to read the TIFF files in parallel and then arrange them into a Dask Array

I encourage you to take a look at [this blogpost on loading image data with Dask](https://blog.dask.org/2019/06/20/load-image-data), which does something similar.

I believe that the `skimage.io.imread` function will happily read data from a URL, although it may not know how to interoperate with GCS.  If the data on GCS is also available by a public URL (this is easy to do if you have access to the GCS bucket) then that would be easy.  Otherwise you might use the [gcsfs](https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library to get the bytes from the file and then feed those bytes into some Python image reader.